# Powershell replacing filenames with parent folder name without changing file endings

Tags: file, powershell, rename, windows-server-2012

I have a parent folder with over 1000 level 1 nested folders and thousands of text files inside each folder:

```
Parent folder ==> Folder1 ==> File1.txt
Parent folder ==> Folder1 ==> File2.txt
Parent folder ==> Folder1 ==> File3.txt
Parent folder ==> Folder2 ==> File1.txt
Parent folder ==> Folder2 ==> File2.txt
Parent folder ==> Folder2 ==> File3.txt
Parent folder ==> Folder3 ==> File1.txt
Parent folder ==> Folder3 ==> File2.txt
Parent folder ==> Folder3 ==> File3.txt
```

I need to be able to rename the files with PowerShell as follows:

```
Parent folder ==> Folder1 ==> Folder1_File1.txt
Parent folder ==> Folder1 ==> Folder1_File2.txt
Parent folder ==> Folder1 ==> Folder1_File3.txt
Parent folder ==> Folder2 ==> Folder2_File1.txt
Parent folder ==> Folder2 ==> Folder2_File2.txt
Parent folder ==> Folder2 ==> Folder2_File3.txt
Parent folder ==> Folder3 ==> Folder3_File1.txt
Parent folder ==> Folder3 ==> Folder3_File2.txt
Parent folder ==> Folder3 ==> Folder3_File3.txt
```

Is there a way of doing this in PowerShell, Windows Server 2012

Thank you ahead of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dir C:\temp\folder\ -directory | % {dir $_.fullname | % {ren $_.fullname $((split-path (split-path $_.fullname) -leaf) + '_' + $_.name)}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply Anthony, do I need to make any loops or will this work for all folders and files underneath the parent folder?

Comment: i just added -directory. this will work for folders directly inside 'folder'. create your sample folder structure to test it out.